# EditText loses focus after Activity transition

Tags: android, android-edittext, activity-transition

I have an **Activity A** and **Activity B**. Both in their layout they have a toolbar but Activity B has an `EditText` below it's toolbar:

**Activity B:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        ...
                        android:hint="@string/hint"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/customCursor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  ... <!--the remaining of the layout-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity A:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>
    ... <!--the remaining of the layout-->
</LinearLayout>
```

When I start **Activity B** without a transition animation the EditText has it's hint displayed and the cursor blinking.
If I start **Activity B** with a transition the EditText doesn't show the hint nor the cursor until I click in it.

Transition code:

```
if (mUseCompatAnimation) {
     ViewCompat.setTransitionName(findViewById(R.id.activity_AppBarLayout), VIEW_FOR_TRANSITION);
}
```

VIEW_FOR_TRANSITION = **Activity A** toolbar

I've tried requesting the focus programmatically but it didn't work.
Am I missing something or this could be a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: try adding dealy of 2 seconds and request focus .